# line spacing in label + vb.net

Tags: vb.net, label, spacing

I have a .NET 2.0 standard Label on my form, well I put some text in it with several lines. But the spacing between the lines are too small. Just want to know if there's a way to fix this.

Thanks...

Comment: That's not an available option, TextRenderer observes font layout rules.  Technically it is possible by overriding OnPaint() and measuring and drawing each line yourself.  Painful.

Comment: Really Painful! Thnx anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can see would be to make multiple labels and space the labels appropriately.

You may need to create the labels dynamically, one per line.

Of course, you could do a .Split(vbNewLine) on the text you want to display and then for each string in the list, create a new label control, adding it to the form, and spacing it out appropriately from the previous label.

Not ideal, but about the only way to accomplish it.

Comment: Well I think that's the only for now! Might takes memory and speed, but I'll see the necessity of this problem, maybe I should give up!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative way to work out that you use the WinformHTMLTextBox then embed the content by using html code which you can employ the advantage of CSS.